# Embed merged URL in a document from Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am working on an Apex Controller which generates a word document. I need to insert a merged URL in the word document depending on the Account that is selected. For ex, if the Account is google, the account object will have an `Account_URL__c` field with the value (www.google.com) and I need to place this value in the word document, but it should be appearing as a hyperlink.

```
<apex:outputLink value=" {!acc.Account_URL__c}" id="accountURL">{!acc.Account_URL__c}</apex:outputLink>
```

This displays the URL on the word document, however, I am not able to do a Ctrl-Click and open the page. When I hover the mouse on the URL, I am seeing the actual URL as `file:///c:\users\balaji\Downloads\+http://www.google.com`. When I click on the URL, it is trying to open the above URL as a link and fails with the message:

> "An unexpected error has occurred.".

Comment: It is actually a visual force page. I have added the code like as shown in my original comment.

Comment: Have you tried to remove space from value <apex:outputLink value="{!acc.Account_URL__c}" id="accountURL"/> ?